# MDX example in VB.NET

Tags: .net, mdx, dmx-ssas

I have a chunk of [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiDimensional_eXpressions) that I'd like to throw into an ASP.NET form.  Hopefully just binding the results to a gridview.  Are there any good links or snippets?  I'm using VB.NET, but I am able to port from C# if no Visual Basic code is available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to execute MDX withing SQL, which I suppose would give you a sneaky way to bind the results to a gridview!

```
select top 100 * from openrowset(
    'MSOLAP',
    'Datasource=MyDBServerName;Initial catalog=MyCubeName',
    'SELECT {dimensions(0).members} on rows, 
    {time.defaultmember} on columns 
    from sales'
)
```

There is a proper way of course (used to be called ADOMD in classic ASP, which gave you a Cellset object you could loop around).

Many people use a third-party .NET component, such as the one by Dundas, to show tables and graphs from cube data.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might come a "little" late, and maybe I misunderstood your question. But if you want to display a grid with the results from MDX queries you can check this sample tutorial on codeproject. I have personally tried it and it worked just fine for me. Combine it with some charting libraries and you can develop this prototype furthermore.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28290/Microsoft-Analysis-Services-2005-Displaying-a-grid

It will basically help you build and understand how to work with CellSets, in a practical and step by step approach. the result will more or less look like in the below picture, just a tiny bit more like 2020 :) You can easily customize it with some personal css or why not Bootstrap.

[image]